# Calculate a table of index vectors for the case $m =40$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruence-relations

I need help calculating a table of index vectors when $m =40$. I also want to know how to use the table to solve $13x^2 \equiv 21 \bmod 40$. Any help is appreicated

Comment: $40$ does not have a primitive root.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first ask for $13y \equiv 21 \bmod 40$, we'll find $y=17+40n$, a number that always ends with $7$, something squares never do...

PS: Sorry I don't know what you mean by "table of index vectors".

Comment: I think It is also called the "table of indices"

Comment: @Kay maybe this link to [Wiki:Primitive root modulo n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) helps. Good luck...

Answer (score 1):

$13x^2 \equiv 21 \bmod 40$ reduces to $3x^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 5$ or $x^2 \equiv 2 \bmod 5$, which has no solutions.